# I have chat message where div is falling down

Tags: css

I have chat message div which `floats` `left` and `right` but I when the reply is more than one lines then div falls down.

Please check my codepen [div falling down](http://codepen.io/ntdropper/pen/EyZZjr)

I want this output:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't let your `bubble` float, instead use a left margin.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grddmW

edit: I updated the code. The same goes for the right floating bubbles, of course.

```
.message .bubble {
    background: #f0f4f7;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 12px 13px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
    color: #717070;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 160px;
}

#chat-messages div.message.right .bubble {
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
    margin-right: 160px;
    max-width: 79%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

In both cases, no floating, but a margin to the left / to the right.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but I want the 'bubble' div to be flexible. 'bubble' div should be resized according to the reply